Blank page after migrating WordPress to a local domain
I need some help.
I just migrated a WordPress webpage to a local server (running on ubuntu 24.04 in Vbox) for some testing. But when opening locally in browser it's blank - no error code, no information, just nothing.
Steps I did:

Installed locally latest Nginx, MySQL, PHP8.3, and all dependencies.
Created locally a database in SQL, created user, assigned priviledges, etc.
Create local site.local folder in /var/www/
Configured Nginx /etc/nginx/sites-available/site.local to listen to port 80, handle php, logs, etc., and created a simlink to /sites-enabled ; restarted nginx, php, all works good
Downloaded a fresh wordpress pack of files and moved to /var/www/site.local/ ;configured wp-config.php to point to database created. I was able to start a fresh wordpress configuration in browser - all good so far
I downloaded the database from the remote website, downloaded wp-content
Deleted all tables in the local db, and replaced them with the downloaded tables
Replaced local wp-content with the replaced one
Changed the prefix in wp-config.php so it's aligned with tables names
Changed the links in the 'options' table so they point to site.local

But when trying to get to the site.local in browser, it's just blank - no 404, 403, etc. just pure blank. It seems it has problems loading the downloaded content.
What am I missing?
Thanks!
As described above - I tried migrating the webpage to a local server, I expected the content opens locally.

wordpress v 6.6.2, nginx v 1.24, mysql v. 8.039, php v 8.3.6

and the server error logs? also try define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); in wp-config

Yea there are a few ways to do that first of all is your wp-config file where you can enable debugging of error by adding these codes
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);

And after Check for errors in wp-content/debug.log and /var/log/nginx/error.log. Ensure proper permissions (e.g., chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/site.local). Verify siteurl and home values in the wp_options table point to http://site.local. If you can't access the admin panel, try regenerating .htaccess with WordPress default rules. Finally, disable plugins and switch to a default theme to check for compatibility issues.
